# Mysql WorkBench Community Edition won't start via terminal

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I try to run Work Bench from command Line:

```
sudo mysql-workbench-community
```

This happens:

```
    mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
    Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.locale” has path “/system/locale/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
    Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy” has path “/system/proxy/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
    Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.http” has path “/system/proxy/http/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
    Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.https” has path “/system/proxy/https/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
    Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp” has path “/system/proxy/ftp/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
    Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.socks” has path “/system/proxy/socks/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
    /snap/mysql-workbench-community/9/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0: /snap/mysql-workbench-community/9/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7: no version information available (required by /snap/mysql-workbench-community/9/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0)
    Using /snap/mysql-workbench-community/9/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.
    /snap/mysql-workbench-community/9/usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: /snap/mysql-workbench-community/9/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7: no version information available (required by /snap/mysql-workbench-community/9/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0)
    Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
    
    (mysql-workbench-bin:25805): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:02:23.059: cannot open display: :0
```

mysql --version

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.21.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

mysql-workbench-community --version

```
enter code here
```

Linux version:

```
Ubuntu LTS 20.4
```

Comment: Why are you trying to run MySQL Workbench with `sudo`? Is the goal to connect to the `root` MySQL account? 

Comment: @matigo yes, however I do not think SUDO is the culpirt here :(

Comment: The reason I asked about `sudo` wasn't so much because of `sudo`, but because of `root` 

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of Ubuntu will not allow people to connect to the `root` MySQL account with external applications. This is because the only time a person is expected to use `root` is when they're setting up the server for the first time or fixing something that has gone horribly, horribly wrong. While you *can* modify MySQL to allow connections with `root`, it is not recommended. Instead, common practise is to create an administrator account that has all of the permissions needed for the job.

Here is how you can create an admin account that you can use and is essentially `root`:

1. On the Ubuntu system running the server, connect to MySQL via the command line:

   ```
   sudo mysql
   ```
2. Create a new user account:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** If you already have an account that you would like to use, this step can be skipped.</sup>
3. Grant that account full access to everything, including the ability to create new accounts:

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   ```
4. Flush the privileges to ensure everything is set:

   ```
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
5. Exit MySQL

Now, in MySQL Workbench — or any other tool that you prefer — connect using the new account that you have just created and elevated.